# Como saber que condicion del if se esta cumpliendo en PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo una sentencia `IF` con varias condiciones `OR` hay alguna manera de saber que condición se esta cumpliendo:

```
if ($variables_tax_id_next == 201 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 206 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 211 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 216 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 226 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 231 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 201 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 206 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 211 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 216 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 226 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 231){

}
```

Comment: Utiliza la estructura de control `switch`

Comment: Tal como está planteada tu aplicación, es un NO rotundo. No hay manera de saber qué condición en concreto es la que se cumple. Como te muestran los compañeros en sus respuestas, existe posibilidad de "acotar" la condición, pero en cualquier caso, no te revelan la condición, sino el valor de la variable. Si pudieras explicar un poco más cuales son tus intenciones, sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @skycomputer2 no olvides marcar la respuesta que te parezca correcta. Saludos

Comment: @skycomputer2 veo que aún no has marcado ninguna de las respuestas a tus preguntas como aceptada. Si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician). De lo contrario, por favor comenta qué faltaría.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes usar la función [in_array](http://php.net/in_array).

Como estás usando los mismos números en la la condición `if`
para las variables `$..._next` y `$..._prev`, he creado un array (`$num`) y con eso haces la comprobación:

```
$num = [201, 206, 211, 216, 226, 231];

if (in_array($variables_tax_id_next, $num)) {

    echo "Valor next: {$variables_tax_id_next}\n";
}

if (in_array($variables_tax_id_prev, $num)) {

    echo "Valor prev: {$variables_tax_id_prev}";
}
```

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/731a7ed80ba409d9fc2c4d43c6cf5b876b9e3b30)**

Answer (score 3):

Realmente al ser una condición lógica `OR` si cualquiera de las opciones es verdadera la condición ingresará, lo que podrías hacer es imprimir el valor de `$variables_tax_id_next` dentro de la condición verdadera y ver que valor tiene esa variable, aunque si envías un solo valor en esa variable, el `if` se podría reemplazar por un `switch`, de tal forma que tengas más control en cada caso.

```
switch ($variables_tax_id_next) {
      case 201:
        echo $variables_tax_id_next;
        break;
      case 206:
        .
        . 
        .
      default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Es lo mismo que si pone un echo $variables_tax_id_next en su código... En realidad no conoce la condición por la que se entra, solo el valor de esta.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber cual de las condiciones se esta cumpliendo, te sugiero usar un switch case, aquí esta la referencia.

http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch ($variables_tax_id_next) {
    case "201":
        echo "Mi valor es". $variable_tax_id_next;
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ademas del `SWITCH`, que la recomendación, también puedes jugar con el `ìf` y el `else if`

```
if ($variables_tax_id_next == 201){
else if( $variables_tax_id_next == 206){
else if( $variables_tax_id_next == 211){
else if( $variables_tax_id_next == 216){
else if( $variables_tax_id_next == 226){
else if( $variables_tax_id_next == 231){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 201){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 206){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 211){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 216){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 226){
else if( $variables_tax_id_prev == 231){
    }
```

Comment: Creo que para evitar algo así es que existe la estructura de control switch.

Comment: @Dev.Joel tienes razón, que lo mejor es el switch, de echo, es la recomendación que hago, si bien esta estructura también es una opción, aunque menos recomendable

Comment: Es una opción. Más no la mejor. Estoy de acuerdo.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es con el switch, aunque propongo la siguiente, ya que se quiere saber cual es la condición se cumplió:

```
if ($variables_tax_id_next == 201 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 206 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 211 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 216 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 226 || 
    $variables_tax_id_next == 231 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 201 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 206 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 211 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 216 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 226 || 
    $variables_tax_id_prev == 231){
    echo "El valor de la variable es ".$variables_tax_id_prev."<br />";
}
```

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Tal como está planteada, cualquiera de las sentencias dentro del `if()` que sea TRUE dará como verdadero el IF, entonces, con esta estructura no se puede obtener lo que quieres. Para saber cual es el valor que llegó lo mejor es usar un `switch`. Ahora, como parece que `$variables_tax_id_next` es un número, tal vez te sirva medirlo mediante algún límite, por ejemplo

```
if ($variables_tax_id_next > 230 && $variables_tax_id_next > 259){
  ...
}else if ($variables_tax_id_next > 260 && ...)...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes intentar con lo siguiente:

```
if (intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 201 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 206 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 211 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 216 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 226 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 231 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 201 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 206 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 211 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 216 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 226 || 
    intval($variables_tax_id_next) === 231){
echo "resultado correcto";
}
```

como estas comparando con resultados enteros a veces php no interpreta las variables como enteras por eso el intval.

espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos.